# The loss of full connected neural network doesn't fall training with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm using tensorflow to train my own fully connected network, but the loss of the network is no longer changed after a significant drop in the first few iterations and the loss has been hovering around 4.3. I don't know where there is a problem. Changing learning rate does not seem to help.

The sample input(named 'feat' in code) I used in the data set is a sparse vector of length 13294, of which only about five positions are valid, and the rest is assigned to 1. A batch of train_x looks like:

```
[[1 1 1 1 1 1... - 96...1 1 1 1... - 84...1 1 1 1... - 56...1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1... - 47...1 1 1 1 1... - 52...1 1 1 1 1.......1 1 1 1 1]
 ...
]
```

The label of the sample is a single value and the value is between 0 and 137. A batch of train_y looks like:

```
[
28
28
110
34
...
]
```

And I have got 26816 training samples using for training.

The code used is shown below

```
"""Neural network applied with tensroflow.

"""

from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

file_wifi_feat = 'wifi_feat.npy'
file_shop_label = 'shop_label.npy'
num_shops = 137
num_wifis = 13294
num_hidden_1 = 8192
num_hidden_2 = 2048
num_hidden_3 = 512
num_hidden_4 = 128
num_hidden_5 = 64


class BatchReader:
    def __init__(self, feat, label):
        self.shuffle = True
        self.feat = []
        self.label = []
        self.batch_offset = 0
        self._load_data(feat, label)

    def _load_data(self, feat, label):
        self.feat = np.load(feat)
        self.label = np.load(label)

    def next_batch(self, batch_size):
        start = self.batch_offset
        self.batch_offset += batch_size
        if self.batch_offset > self.feat.shape[0]:
            perm = np.arange(self.feat.shape[0])
            np.random.shuffle(perm)
            self.feat = self.feat[perm]
            self.label = self.label[perm]
            start = 0
            self.batch_offset = batch_size
        end = self.batch_offset
        batch_feat = np.array([m.toarray()[0] for m in self.feat[start:end]])
        batch_feat[np.where(batch_feat == 0)] = 1
        batch_label = self.label[start:end]
        return batch_feat, batch_label


def weight_variable(shape):
    """weight_variable generates a weight variable of a given shape."""
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.get_variable(name='weights', initializer=initial)


def bias_variable(shape):
    """bias_variable generates a bias variable of a given shape."""
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.get_variable(name='bias', initializer=initial)


def main(argv=None):
    batch_reader = BatchReader(file_wifi_feat, file_shop_label)

    feat_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_wifis])
    label_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

    with tf.variable_scope('h1'):
        weight = weight_variable([num_wifis, num_hidden_1])
        bias = bias_variable([num_hidden_1])
        L1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(feat_ph, weight) + bias)

    with tf.variable_scope('h2'):
        weight = weight_variable([num_hidden_1, num_hidden_2])
        bias = bias_variable([num_hidden_2])
        L2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(L1, weight) + bias)

    with tf.variable_scope('h3'):
        weight = weight_variable([num_hidden_2, num_hidden_3])
        bias = bias_variable([num_hidden_3])
        L3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(L2, weight) + bias)

    with tf.variable_scope('h4'):
        weight = weight_variable([num_hidden_3, num_hidden_4])
        bias = bias_variable([num_hidden_4])
        L4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(L3, weight) + bias)

    with tf.variable_scope('h5'):
        weight = weight_variable([num_hidden_4, num_hidden_5])
        bias = bias_variable([num_hidden_5])
        L5 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(L4, weight) + bias)

    with tf.variable_scope('hypo'):
        weight = weight_variable([num_hidden_5, num_shops])
        bias = bias_variable([num_shops])
        hypothesis = tf.matmul(L5, weight) + bias

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=hypothesis, labels=label_ph))
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(hypothesis, 1), tf.cast(label_ph, tf.int64))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
    starter_learning_rate = 0.1
    learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step, 20, 0.96, staircase=True)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    sess = tf.Session(config=config)
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for itr in xrange(100001):
        feat, label = batch_reader.next_batch(256)
        feed_dict = {feat_ph: feat, label_ph: label}
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict)
        # hypothesis_val = sess.run(hypothesis, feed_dict=feed_dict)
        if itr % 10 == 0:
            loss_val, accuracy_val, learning_rate_val = sess.run([loss, accuracy, learning_rate], feed_dict=feed_dict)
            print('Step %d, loss %g, accuracy %g, learning_rate %g' % (itr, loss_val, accuracy_val, learning_rate_val))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

The output looks like this(loss doesn't change much even have run to step 10000)：

```
Step 0, loss 1.41158e+09, accuracy 0.03125, learning_rate 0.1
Step 10, loss 4.68047, accuracy 0.0273438, learning_rate 0.1
Step 20, loss 4.54852, accuracy 0.0234375, learning_rate 0.096
Step 30, loss 4.22673, accuracy 0.0546875, learning_rate 0.096
Step 40, loss 4.36984, accuracy 0.0390625, learning_rate 0.09216
Step 50, loss 4.26286, accuracy 0.0546875, learning_rate 0.09216
Step 60, loss 4.4269, accuracy 0.0546875, learning_rate 0.0884736
Step 70, loss 4.21976, accuracy 0.105469, learning_rate 0.0884736
Step 80, loss 4.39736, accuracy 0.0546875, learning_rate 0.0849346
Step 90, loss 4.32979, accuracy 0.0820312, learning_rate 0.0849346
Step 100, loss 4.38875, accuracy 0.078125, learning_rate 0.0815373
Step 110, loss 4.37169, accuracy 0.0898438, learning_rate 0.0815373
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the loss obtained in iteration 1 shows that your network is horribly initialised. The initial loss should not be bigger than 10, yet in your case it is 1e9. Decrease the std in initialisations of your network by at least an order of magnitude. In general you should not initialise variables by hand, use a well known heuristics such as Xavier initialiser (ready to use in TF).

Second thing is data normalisation - according to the snippet provided your data is huge, make sure that each feature dimension has 0 mean and std 1. It is really important, especially with relu activations which can go "dead" with too big signals.

Finally - one should not start with complex architecture, why do you have 5 hidden layers and complex learning rate schedule to start with? These are things that should be added **as needed**, not used as default. Many of the above problems would be avoided by simply starting with fixed learning rate (even the default one) and small network - say 1-2 hidden layers. Once it is not enough - going deeper / to more advanced methods is a good idea, but starting with it makes it much harder to understand why things are going badly.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I modified the number of layers and the current network is a structure only containing one hidden layer. I calculate the mean of training set and send `train_x - mean` to the neural network instead of original `train_x`. I modified the initialization method to Xavier. The loss decreases as expected. But I have faced with a new problem while dealing with the over-fitting problem. I post a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46945286/encounter-strange-phenomenon-while-using-l2-regularization-and-dropout-to-suppre), and hope to get you help.

Answer (score -1):

I think you made an error with your global_step.

Generally tf.Variable is used in a network to automatically update is value in training phase. Furthermore you initialize global_step as tf.Variable but you set it as non-trainable and set value to 0.

You can find more informations about variables on documentation : https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables

Hope to help you.

Comment: Also I suggest you to start with fixed learning rate and pass it to your optimizer. Then If your loss decrease try to use adaptive learning rate.

Comment: What OP is doing is is exactly how global_step should be used.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The problem you point out may be one of the reasons but not the most critical. I refer to the [official documents](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train/decaying_the_learning_rate) speaking of the usage of `global_step`. I have figured out this problem using the method mentioned by @lejlot. Now I face a new problem when dealing with the over-fitting, would you mind have a look on [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46945286/encounter-strange-phenomenon-while-using-l2-regularization-and-dropout-to-suppre)? Thank you.